# blinking cursor in the left when booting from the harddrive but works fine from flash drive

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, system-installation

I am installing ubuntu for the first time. I got ubuntu installed on a flash drive and can boot from said drive. I have installed ubuntu on my hard drive as the only OS on the hard drive. It doesn't boot. It loads the hp loading screen and then goes to a blinking cursor in the upper left. Holding shift or hitting escape does not bring up the grub menu.

I am wondering what i did wrong. 
I ran boot repair didn't seem to help.
Here is the feedback file they provided.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7506978/

Thanks in advance,
Greg

Answer (score -1):

Same happened to me, ran repair etc, re-installed twice the second time without internet access and it booted up ok.

Comment: I installed three times now, but i haven't tried it without Ethernet plugged in. I'll give it a shot. Did you partition the drive yourself or just leave the defaults? (ubuntu is the only OS on my system so I left the defaults twice and tried partitioning myself once)